# Why my .h5 file trained locally only recognizes one option?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5

Sorry for bothering, and if i spell something wrong, i haven't practised my english in a while! Well, i'm following a yt tutorial which trains a cnn to recognize facial expressions. The problem is that when i try it locally with my own .h5 file generated by the training, it only returns the same option even though my face change.

On the other hand, (i have not changed the code), i've tried with the .h5 generated by the yt tutorial and it works!

Searching for the differences, i have found different things, can you help me?

The CNN is configured this way (i haven't changed it):

> model = Sequential()
>
> model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = 'same',input_shape = (48,48,1)))
> model.add(BatchNormalization()) model.add(Activation('relu'))
> model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))) model.add(Dropout(0.25))
>
> model.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5),padding = 'same'))
> model.add(BatchNormalization()) model.add(Activation('relu'))
> model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))) model.add(Dropout (0.25))
>
> model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),padding = 'same'))
> model.add(BatchNormalization()) model.add(Activation('relu'))
> model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))) model.add(Dropout (0.25))
>
> model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
> model.add(BatchNormalization()) model.add(Activation('relu'))
> model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) model.add(Dropout(0.25))
>
> model.add(Flatten())
>
> model.add(Dense(256)) model.add(BatchNormalization())
> model.add(Activation('relu')) model.add(Dropout(0.25))
>
> model.add(Dense(512)) model.add(BatchNormalization())
> model.add(Activation('relu')) model.add(Dropout(0.25))
>
> model.add(Dense(no_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
>
> opt = Adam(lr = 0.0001)
> model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='categorical_crossentropy',
> metrics=['accuracy']) model.summary()

And comparing both .h5 files, these are the following results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4uS6.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of one of your true labels? Also can you update your question with how you defined your datasets. Also, are you (as in you, your face) part of the training data or just test data? Or is the training data already large and diverse enough?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.